# Can I play saints row 4 alternate ending after finishing the original ending?

Tags: pc, saints-row-iv

I have completed the game before I did all my loyalty missions and now want to watch the cutscene of the other ending

> (the time travel one)

and even after I did all the missions, I can't seem to play the alternate ending. I have an old save just before finale no.1 but I don't want to play all those loyalty missions again. Can I play that mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to unlock the other ending is to complete **all the** Loyalty Missions. You may get a save game from internet for playing only the ending if you wish to, but then the difference is only the last cutscene; the Boss fight itself is not different. You may also search for it on YouTube if you don't want to go through the entire fleet of Loyalty Missions.

Comment: There's a minor difference in the boss fight, during the last phase every member of the bosses crew flies down on jetbikes to help out, but they don't actually do anything to impact the fight.